# How can I select the columns names where a condition is met

Tags: pandas

I need to select column names where the count is greater than 2. I have this dataset:

```
    Index | col_1 | col_2 | col_3 | col_4 
    -------------------------------------
      0   |   5   |  NaN  |   4   |  2
      1   |   2   |   2   |  NaN  |  2
      2   |  NaN  |   3   |  NaN  |  1
      3   |   3   |  NaN  |  NaN  |  1
```

The expected result is a list: ['col_1', 'col_4']

When I use

```
    df.count() > 2
```

I get

```
    col_1 True
    col_2 False
    col_3 False
    col_4 True
    Length: 4, dtype: bool
```

This is the code for testing

```
    import pandas as pd
    import numpy as np

    data = {'col_1': [5, 2, np.NaN, 3],
            'col_2': [np.NaN, 2, 3, np.NaN],
            'col_3': [4, np.NaN, np.NaN, np.NaN],
            'col_4': [2, 2, 1,1]}

    frame = pd.DataFrame(data)

    frame.count() > 2
```

Comment: just use: `df.loc[:,df.count()>2]` for columns `df.loc[:,df.count()>2].columns`

Answer (score 0):

You can do it this way.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = {'col_1': [5, 2, np.NaN, 3],
        'col_2': [np.NaN, 2, 3, np.NaN],
        'col_3': [4, np.NaN, np.NaN, np.NaN],
        'col_4': [2, 2, 1,1]}

frame = pd.DataFrame(data)

expected_list = []
for col in list(frame.columns):
    if frame[col].count() > 2:
        expected_list.append(col)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `dict` can easily solve this:

```py
frame[[key for key, value in dict(frame.count() > 2).items() if value]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

`(df.columns)[(df.count() > 2).values].to_list()`